# How to count the number of times a word appears for specific fields using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is my file.

[image: Image of a fixed with file with 4 columns: an unnamed integer, empId, alert, alertId]

I have to find the number of times each alert(fall, distress etc.) occurs for each empId(say PBE001,PBE002 etc.)
How to count it?

Comment: What did you try? What issues did you meet? You're expected to show your effort, and to ask for a _specific_ problem

Comment: Also, have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groupby()` function  in pandas and then count the number of instances you need.

Just make sure you do the following - always assign your groupby() and aggregates to a name/variable otherwise it will not work.

Secondly, make sure you combine this with an aggregate function - whether it is `.sum()` or `.count()` etc. etc.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('empId').count()
```